Getting Data from EF Core using a Pooled DbContext and Hot Chocolate
I'm learning about GraphQL with .NET Core, I have a basic project set up.
At the moment I'm using a repository that contains a IDbContextFactory since my DbContext is pooled.
I can make use of this repository in my Query/Mutations and the api calls work as expected.
I am now, instead of using a repository, trying to inject the DbContext as a Service to my query/mutation methods but I am getting this code 500 error - Unexpected Execution Error.
It seems in my logs that the query just stops after trying to query from the Courses table.

This is my code
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(opts => {
    opts.UseSqlite(connectionString);
});

builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
    .AddSubscriptionType<Subscription>()
    .AddInMemorySubscriptions()
    .RegisterDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(DbContextKind.Pooled)
    .AddQueryType<Query>();


Query.cs
public class Query {


    public async Task<IEnumerable<CourseType>> GetCoursesWithDbParameter(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        IEnumerable<CourseDto> courseDtos = await context.Courses.ToListAsync();

        return courseDtos.Select(x => new CourseType() {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Subject = x.Subject
        });
    }

}

I also wanted to know, which method should be preferred in this case? Is there a benefit to injecting an available context from the pool within my query/mutation methods itself?
Thank you

Could you please tell me how you use this query/mutation methods ? Directly inside each class? Or this query contains the construct method and you register this query class at program.cs?

I don't understand sorry, but I have this Query class with my resolvers, and another class for Mutations for create,update and delete operations.
Then I just call the method names with the GraphQL Client.
Please let me know if there's anything else @BrandoZhang

When you're using HotChocolate's RegisterDbContext, you're required to register the db context service into .NET DI container using services.AddDbContext<T>() call. See: https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/integrations/entity-framework/#registerdbcontext
